# Sveltekit authentication using Laravel Sanctum

Tags: javascript, laravel, svelte, laravel-sanctum, sveltekit

I want to ask how to do the authentication using sveltekit and Laravel sanctum, I have already set up the backend and am able to log in using email and password. I tried a cookie-based session, using hooks.js and endpoint in sveltekit but I got confused. What is the best way to authenticate the user and protect some routes using sveltekit using laravel sanctum?

```
    // src/routes/login.svelte
    <script>
    let email;
    let password;

    function login() {
        fetch('/login', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ email, password })
        });
    }
    </script>

    <h1>Login Page</h1>

    <form on:submit|preventDefault={login}>
        <input bind:value={email} type="text" name="email" placeholder="email" />
        <input bind:value={password} type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

```
    // src/routes/login.js
    export async function post(request) {
        await fetch('http://localhost:8000/sanctum/csrf-cookie');

        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/login', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                accept: 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(request.body)
        });

        const user = await response.json();

        request.locals.user = user
    
        return {
            status: response.status,
            body: user
        }
    }
```

```
    // src/hooks.js
    export async function handle({ request, resolve }) {
        const cookies = cookie.parse(request.headers.cookie || '')
        
        request.locals.user = cookies.user
        
        const response = await resolve(request)
        
        response.headers['set-cookie'] = `user=${request.locals.user || ''}; Path=/; HttpOnly`
        
        return response
    }
    
    
    export async function getSession(request) {
        return {
            user: request.locals.user
        }
    }
```

```
    // src/routes/__layout.svelte
    <script context="module">
        export async function load({ session }) {
            return {
                props: {
                    user: session.user
                }
            };
        }
    </script>
    
    <script>
        export let user;
    </script>
    
    <nav class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
            <li><a href="/dashboard">Dashboar</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div>{user}</div>
    </nav>
    
    <slot />
```

Comment: In order for people to better support you with your question please add a bit more information about what you have already tried. It is easier to help when getting a glance of your code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like no one could answer this.

Just follow my guide here: https://github.com/daison12006013/sveltekit-starter/blob/develop/guides/laravel-sanctum.md

Basically you need the laravel sanctum to inject a cookie based login